# How to capture video from an encrypted video streaming website?

Tags: video-download

Videos of some video streaming websites like YouTube can be easily captured to be watched again without incurring data expenses.

However, some sites use encryption and many downloader tools can't detect the video and won't download it.

What are the options to get video from those sites?

Using `ChromeCacheView` I can see that `vide/MP2T` is getting downloaded inside cache, but it disappears almost immediately.

Comment: if you can play it = you downloading it to your cache = you just need to extract it (in a worst case - merge it) - https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that utility. Question updated.